# is there a browser that disables the rendering of images?

Tags: browser

I was just curious if there is a web browser for ubuntu that has the option to not show images and other resources like flash and videos for example.

(I do recall being able to play with a browser that uses the terminal to render the html page but do I have options other than that one?)

Comment: And now both Chrome and Firefox have a "click-to-play" option for plug-ins. In other words, things like Flash or Java won't run unless you specifically allow them each time (or always for sites of your choosing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is entirely what you are after, but lynx is a text only browser for Linux? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lynx

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome (or Chromium), Firefox. If you use Chrome lookee here http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/03/how-to-block-images-in-chromium-and.html

Comment: yep, that seems to be working. actually ff and chromium have the options to disable the picture rendering. thanks for the answer :D